# I don't understand the difference in output between System.out.println((char)b) and System.out.write((char)b)

Tags: java, binary, character

I don't understand the difference  in output between System.out.println((char)b) and System.out.write((char)b) in this example.

```
class WriteDemo {
    public static void main(String args[])
    throws IOException {
    byte data[] = new byte[10];
    int b;
    b = 'é';
    System.out.println((char)b);
    System.out.write((char)b);
    System.out.write('\n');
    }
}
```

System.out.println((char)b) prints é whereas System.out.write((char)b) prints Ú.

I don't understand why?

It probably has something to do with bits being discarded but I simply can't seem to figure out how it get to the letter Ú.

Comment: My output: 2 `é`

Comment: Weird. I'm getting é and Ú as output

Comment: https://ideone.com/srCSP4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`write` writes a *byte* to the output stream.

`print` writes a *character* to the output stream.

`print` also uses the platform's default encoding while `write` will write the byte as given according to the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#write-int-).

Quote from the  `write` docs:

> to write a character that will be translated according to the platform's default character encoding, use the print(char) or println(char) methods.

Note: `char` is 16 bit, while `byte` is 8 bit, i.e. a `char` is two `bytes` thus losing information in the process of conversion.

EDIT:

The reason why `write` is outputting that character for you is because you are basically doing this:

```
System.out.write((byte) 233); //233 is Integer.valueOf('é')
```

Which is the same as this:

```
System.out.write(0xE9);
```

So in the encoding you are using where you print it `0xE9` is `Ú`.

Additionally, the reason why these end up printing as two different characters in the console is likely due to the `char` getting translated to the correct encoding for `print` and *then* printing in the same encoding as it was translated to, but because `write` writes the literal byte AND the console attempts to translate the byte into the current encoding *anyway* after the fact, it results in an incorrect character appearing.  The character that appears will change depending on what the console encoding is set to, commonly `Cp1252` or `UTF-8`.

If you change your console encoding to `ISO-8859-1`, then `0xE9` will print the `é` correctly and in both cases you included.

Comment: That does not explain why I get the same output for each print or write.  More than likely it has to do with the chosen `charset` and/or `locale`of the OP.

Comment: @WJS You are most likely using `ISO-8859-1` as your default encoding if you got `é` for both.  I tried to add a better explanation.

Comment: Thanks for you help in figuring this out. I appreciate it very much. I understand now how this works in this case. It is still complicated though. The conversion table that my console in Windows 8 uses to interpret the byte apparantly is the one of the extended ASCII: https://theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/capital-letter-u-acute-accent-ascii-code-233.html

Comment: @Dennis Versluis Ah thank you for telling me which table you were using, I searched many different encodings to attempt to find which one you were using and I couldn't find the correct one!  Yeah I see the `233` there.